# In Star Trek, how fast is warp 9.99?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The Prometheus class ship is said to be the fastest in Starfleet at a blazing 9.99 warp. Please forgive my maths shortcoming but I can't get my head around this number. I know the equation is here on Stack Exchange and elsewhere but it's Greek to me. I know light speed is 186,000 miles per second and that warp 9.99 is not 186,000 x 9.99. In laymen's terms, how fast is that? Ten times light speed? Ten thousand times light speed? What? Please speak slowly.

Comment: Very fast indeed

Comment: While it's a fine question on its own, I think your claim that Prometheus can go at warp 9.99 is incorrect, both the [memory alpha page for "Prometheus Class"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Prometheus_class) and the [transcript of the episode "Message in a Bottle"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/411.htm) say it can go at least warp 9.9 but don't say whether that's the top speed, and if not how much higher it might be. According to the chart Richard linked to, warp 9.9 would correspond to 3,053 times light speed.

Comment: The fastest ship in Starfleet was actually the shuttle that Tom Paris outfitted from Voyager Series (Warp 10). The following events from Paris & Janeway were so shocking that Starfleet removed it from the official record.

Comment: @Hypnosifl [Voyager's top cruising speed is warp 9.975.](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Voyager#Physical_arrangement) I don't think I have ever seen a reference to its maximum attainable speed, but it logically cannot be *lower* than the ship's top cruising speed. Of course they don't often go that fast.

Comment: Here is the conversion: Warp 9.9=Ridiculous Speed, 9.99=Ludicrous Speed, 9.999=Plaid.

Comment: “Ten thousand times light speed?” Hey, you weren’t far off.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) offers some conversion charts.

**Warp 9.99 is approximately 7,912 times the speed of light.**

[image]

---

As you can see from the handy diagram below, as you approach Warp 10 (infinite speed), your velocity increases exponentially. Warp 9.9 is half the speed of warp 9.99 and warp 9.9999 is over 30 times faster than warp 9.9, etc.

[image]

Comment: Although it's always worth remembering that, in the actual TV shows, there are many instances over the years that contradict the official figures given above.

Comment: Good stuff Richard, thanks for putting that info here in one easy to read post.

Comment: @tojo - Note the disclaimer at the bottom. Your actual mileage may vary! It's best not to look to hard at it and just accept that warp 9 = "very fast" and anything above that = "ludicrously fast".

Comment: I notice the graph says "maximum safe speed" at 9.1, which clearly became incorrect by the time of _Voyager_ seeing as that ship's _cruising_ speed was warp 9.975. Soooo this throws its reliability into question and I don't think you can use it as a source here. Particularly as the curve doesn't actually agree with the mathematics that you describe in the text of your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The note that 9.1 is the maximum safe speed apparently refers to the Enterprise (given that the graph is taken wholesale from the TNG Technical Manual). Different ships will obviously have different safe speeds but that doesn't invalidate the graph. As far as why they don't tally, note the disclaimer. It's also worth pointing out that warp speeds don't necessarily correlate to actual speeds. It's noted that traveling through different densities of space will slow/speed you up. Also, Bellisario's maxim applies (e.g. it's just a show, don't look too hard at it)

Comment: Pretty sure your "also" nails it :D

Comment: The scale was also changed between TOS and TNG

Comment: So what’s explanation again why the future *Enterprise” in “All Good Things” can go warp 13? I remember reading an explanation somewhere but I don’t recall.

Comment: @iMerchant - I seem to recall that the re-calibrated the scale rather than calling it something dumb like Warp 9.9999

Comment: @Valorum - Ah yes. That’s what I read. When did they do that?

Comment: @iMerchant - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35539/warp-13-was-this-overlooked

Comment: @user64334 In the year 2312, the definition of warp changed. Warp used to be the speed of light cubed, so warp 1 was 3c, warp 2 was 9c, warp 3 was 27c, etc.

Answer (score 13):

For a quick calculation, just enter "[warp factor 9.99 TNG](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=warp+factor+9.99+TNG)" in Wolfram Alpha.

The answer is 7912 times the speed of light, but, as [the equation is good up to Warp 9 only](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102838/64573), this number has been

> extrapolated from the hand-drawn curve from the *Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual.*

If you omit the number and the "TNG" part, you get a calculator with a drop-down menu to choose either [TOS or TNG formula](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37487/64573).

Answer (score 2):

A problem with the warp chart is that warp 5 is shown to travel 214 times the speed of light, but that is incorrect according to Star trek enterprise. In Enterprise, the ship can only go at top speed of warp 5, meaning Enterprise could travel 214 light years in one year. But the Enterprise is able to make it to the Klingon home world, Qo'nos, a few weeks. But Qo'nos is in the Leonis system, 108 light years from earth. So going by the warp chart, it should've taken the Enterprise half a year to reach Qo'nos, but that definitely isn't the case.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, from on-screen dialogue, the USS Prometheus traveled towards Romulan space at Warp 9.9 (not 9.99).

Mr. Paris already established earlier on Voyager (on-screen) that Warp 9.9 = 4 billion miles per second (21,473 times the speed of light).

And since no SF ship prior to Voyager (nor even Voyager) was actually seen using Warp 9.9 (even though it was stated that Voyager's cruising speed was Warp 9.975), its safe to say that the writers were overzealous in their sustainable cruise speed for Voyager. Either that... or Voyager was indeed the first ship capable of achieving Warp 9.975, but the damage they suffered in the transition to the DQ destroyed that capability.

And indeed, we mostly see Voyager cruising at Warp 6 back to the Federation, with minor increases to Warp 8 or even 9 to make up for lost time. The only time we saw them using Warp 9.9 was in the episode 'Threshold', and in that episode, when they approached Warp 9.9, the computer said 'nearing maximum Warp velocity, structural collapse is imminent'.Chakotay then ordered to slow down to Warp 9.5 to stop the ship from shaking itself apart.

We also know from TNG 'Where no one has gone before' episode in Season 1, that at Ent-D maximum Warp, it would take the ship just over 300 years to get back to the Federation. At that time, The Enterprise-D could achieve Warp 9.6 for limited period of time (which we could say would be a rough 'maximum velocity).
That's also roughly 9,000 times the speed of light.

Also, there are at least two instances in TNG where raising the velocity of the ship from Warp 8.7, to Warp 9, cut the time needed to arrive at a destination from 14 hours to 5 hours (that's about 180% increase in speed from just 2 decimals).
Most notably, in TNG it was in the episode Gambit (season 7).

So, the Warp scale might make more sense if it was something like this:

- Warp 9.0 = 1,500 times C
- Warp 9.1 = 2,250 times C
- Warp 9.2 = 3,000 times C
- Warp 9.3 = 4,500 times C
- Warp 9.4 = 6,000 times C
- Warp 9.5 = 7,500 times C
- Warp 9.6 = 9,000 times C
- Warp 9.7 = 13,500 times C
- Warp 9.8 = 18,000 times C
- Warp 9.9 = 21,473 times C
- Warp 9.91 = 42,946 times C
- Warp 9.92 = 85,892 times C
- Warp 9.93 = 171,784 times C
- Warp 9.94 = 343,568 times C
- Warp 9.95 = 687,136 times C
- Warp 9.96 = 1,374,272 times C
- Warp 9.97 = 2,748,544 times C
- Warp 9.98 = 5,497,088 times C
- Warp 9.99 = 10,994,176 times C

The base premise behind this is that past Warp 9.9, every increment results in exponential (double) increase in velocity (and also power expenditure).
Granted, SF would eventually find a way to compensate for the power expenditure, and hull stresses, allowing greater speeds at Warp.

The Soliton Wave technology for example resulted in less than 2% drop in power between the wave and a drone test ship... making the Soliton Wave technology about 480% more efficient than standard Warp engines (again, this is taken from on-screen dialogue in TNG).

I wouldn't be surprised if SF decided to use aspects of soliton wave technology to greatly increase the efficiency of Warp engines though.

But, as for the USS Prometheus, the official on-screen dialogue never says what the ship's maximum speed is.
However, when the EMH Mark 1 said they were at Warp 9.9 heading straight for Romulan space, the EMH Mark 2 promptly responded with 'this ship was designed to go faster than anything in the fleet, so we'll never be rescued'.

The USS Prometheus was comfortably sustaining Warp 9.9 without any issues.
But whether that was its maximum speed is unknown.
Warp 9.9 could have been the maximum sustainable cruise velocity for USS Prometheus.

One way of another, what we saw on-screen tells us that Voyager never attained Warp 9.975, let alone sustained it.
It didn't even manage to sustain Warp 9.9 in Threshold episode for more than 30 seconds.
And it was seen cruising usually at Warp 6.

Now, if Paris statement is taken at face value (and he's a Starship pilot), so the claim that Warp 9.9 = 21 473 times C actually fits what we saw generally of most SF ships when they were using Warp from TNG, to DS9, and even VOY.

Comment: I think we've already established above that Paris' quote shouldn't be taken at face value. [He was using hyperbole](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176019/20774)

Comment: Actually, no.
Paris statement makes sense especially if you take into account certain examples of how fast Enterprise-D would take to traverse 2.7 million ly's.
And the premise that from Warp 8.5 to Warp 9, speed was increased by 180% (which clearly indicates larger and larger jumps as you reach and pass Warp 9).
It also stands to reason that exponential increase in velocity would then occur past Warp 9.9 with every increment.

Also, It was clearly stated that the USS PRometheus was traveling at Warp 9.9.
Are you going to argue that was an error too?

Comment: As has been [noted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124718/in-star-trek-how-fast-is-warp-9-99/187891?noredirect=1#comment310191_124719) warp speed is presented very inconsistently, as you'd expect from a show where the top speed of the ship is the _speed of plot_. Trying to shoehorn what's said on-screen into your own fan-theory and playing with maths to make it interesting is fun, but let's not pretend that it's anything more than that.

Comment: So, trying to make sense of what the characters said on-screen and actually reconciling it with the speeds shown on-screen is futile?
By that analogy, this entire discussion and all questions pertaining to Trek are futile

It's fun to think about it... and as for it being my own fan-theory... I have yet to see other theories that reconcile on-screen dialogue with speeds in the manner I described.
I provided logical explanations based on on-screen dialogue and what happened... you however have not really contributed in a similar manner and are using 'speed of the plot' to discredit my post.

Comment: Mind you, 'speed of the plot' is usually what happened, but we are also trying to see how things would fit from an 'in universe' point of view.

Btw, you frequently use that to downvote people (by using real world explanations for what happened), when it suits you, but apparently don't try to find in-universe explanation for why something was said.

Paris didn't seem to be lying or trying to boast when he mentioned how fast Warp 9.9 is. He was simply giving Amelia a better understanding using terminology and metrics she is familiar with. Besides, what would be the point  in lying?

Comment: Also, my so-called 'fan theory' uses canonical data and what we saw  on-screen.
Many other people tend to quote ST Encyclopedia, artistic graphs and Technical Manuals which the writers and people in charge of Trek do NOT consider canon.